# Does Glassfish have /run and /start options similar to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, glassfish

For certain reasons I need to block the command prompt window used to start Glassfish 3.1 server until the server is live however I cannot find the right option to do that. When I execute:
`asadmin start-domain`
it starts the server and returns the from the command. I need something similar to Tomcat's `-run` option that keeps the execution in the same process (in contrast to the `-start` one that spawns separate process.

Any help will be appreciated.

toddysm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [--verbose option](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/start-domain-1.html#start-domain-1).